# Negative margin not working

Tags: html, css, margin

I'm trying to get negative margin to allow my logo to overflow the header.

Image of intended result:
[image: Psd - How it needs to look]

Image showing current, wrong result:
[image: Code - the error]

I'm really new to both HTML and CSS, though I've tried my best in playing around with this code and trying to find answers online (including this website) all to no avail. So here's my code relating to these sections:

```css
#logo {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: -30px 0px -100px 10px;
}
.hheader {
  background-color: #005073;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 60, 80, .8) 0%, rgba(0, 80, 105, .8) 50%, rgba(0, 60, 80, .8) 100%);
  /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 60, 80, .8) 0%, rgba(0, 80, 105, .8) 50%, rgba(0, 60, 80, .8) 100%);
  /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 60, 80, .8) 0%, rgba(0, 80, 105, .8) 50%, rgba(0, 60, 80, .8) 100%);
  /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 60, 80, .8) 0%, rgba(0, 80, 105, .8) 50%, rgba(0, 60, 80, .8) 100%);
  /* Standard syntax */
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 7px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Standard syntax */
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 7px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 7px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: black;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="hheader">
    <a id="logo" href="/" title="Return to home">
      <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Density Art Logo">
    </a>
  </div>
```

And in case it's required, here's the full code for both:

HTML

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Density Art - Home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="hheader">
            <a id="logo" href="/" title="Return to home">
            <img src="images/logo.png" alt="Density Art Logo">
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="nav_menu">
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Website Design</a></li>           
                    <li><a href="#">Art &amp; Poetry</a></li>  
                    <li><a href="#">Blog &amp; Other</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Music &amp; More</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>  
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div> <!-- end of container-->
    </div> <!-- end of navigator menu bar--> 
</header>


    <div id="content">
        <section id="leftcolumn">

            <h1>Home</h1>

            <h3>Who are we?</h3>

            <p>Density art is a small company local to Newcastle, Australia. We produce extremely quality websites, art and poetry alongside other projects that we have discoverdd is in absolutely high demand. You'll completely love all we have to offer so you may enjoy yourself when you will search through our products and buy them.</p>

            <p>Density art is a small company local to Newcastle, Australia. We produce extremely quality websites, art and poetry alongside other projects that we have discoverdd is in absolutely high demand. You'll completely love all we have to offer so you may enjoy yourself when you will search through our products and buy them.</p>

            <h3>What is our aim?</h3>

            <p>Density art is a small company local to Newcastle, Australia. We produce extremely quality websites, art and poetry alongside other projects that we have discoverdd is in absolutely high demand. You'll completely love all we have to offer so you may enjoy yourself when you will search through our products and buy them.</p>

            <p>Density art is a small company local to Newcastle, Australia. We produce extremely quality websites, art and poetry alongside other projects that we have discoverdd is in absolutely high demand. You'll completely love all we have to offer so you may enjoy yourself when you will search through our products and buy them.</p>

        </section> <!-- end of left column content-->

        <aside id="rightcolumn">

            <h2>Get Connected!</h2>
            <h5>Join our evergrowing community and become a part of Density Art</h5>

            <a href="http://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank"><img src="images/btns/fb.png" alt="Facebook"></a>
            <h4>Facebook</h4>

            <a href="http://www.instagram.com/" target="_blank"><img src="images/btns/ig.png" alt="InstaGram"></a>
            <h4>Instagram</h4>

            <a href="http://www.soundcloud.com/" target="_blank"><img src="images/btns/sc.png" alt="SoundCloud"></a>
            <h4>SoundCloud</h4>


            <a href="http://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank"><img src="images/btns/em.png" alt="Email"></a>
            <h4>Email</h4>


            <a href="http://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank"><img src="images/btns/ph.png" alt="Phone Call"></a>
            <h4>Phone Call</h4>


        </aside> <!--end of right column content-->

    </div> <!-- end of content form-->

<footer>
    <div id="footerbar">

        <p>Copyright &copy; informatrion copyright 2001 etc bnlah blah Copyright informatrion copyright 2001 etc bnlah blah Copyright informatrion copyright 2001 etc bnlah blah</p>

        <hr>

        <h6>Contact us</h6>
        <h6>Legal Terms</h6>
        <h6>Shopping Cart</h6>
        <h6>Facebook</h6>
        <h6>Instagram</h6>



    </div>


</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```css
html {
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
text-rendering: optimiszelegibility;   
}


body {
font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
line-height:20px;
color: ebe9e9; 
}

h1, h2 {
font-weight: 700;
margin:0;
line-height: 45px;    
}


h4, h6  {
font-weight: bold;
margin: 5px 0 5px 0;    
}

h1 {
font-size:48px;
}

h2 {
font-size:30px;
}

h3 {
font-size:24px;
font-weight: bold;
}

h4 {
font-size:20px;
line-height: 45px;
}

h5 {
font-size:16px;
font-weight: 600;
margin:0;
line-height: 45px; 
}

h6 {
font-size:12px;
line-height: 20px;
}

p {
margin: 0 0 10px 0;

}

nav ul li{
display: inline;
}

#logo {
display:inline-block;
margin: -30px 0px -100px 10px;
}

.hheader {
background-color: #005073;
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(0,60,80,.8) 0%,        rgba(0,80,105,.8) 50%, rgba(0,60,80,.8) 100%); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(0,60,80,.8) 0%, rgba(0,80,105,.8)  50%, rgba(0,60,80,.8) 100%); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(0,60,80,.8) 0%, rgba(0,80,105,.8) 50%, rgba(0,60,80,.8) 100%); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,60,80,.8) 0%, rgba(0,80,105,.8) 50%, rgba(0,60,80,.8) 100%); /* Standard syntax */
box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 7px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Standard syntax */
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 7px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 7px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
border-color: black;
margin-bottom: 2em;
margin-top: 30px;
}

.container {
width: 960px;
padding: 0 10px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.nav_menu {
background-color: #005073;
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,.3), rgba(125,125,125,.3)); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,.3), rgba(125,125,125,.3)); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,.3), rgba(125,125,125,.3)); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,.3), rgba(125,125,125,.3)); /* Standard syntax */
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);  /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 2px 1x rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Standard syntax */
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
border-color: black;
max-height: 2em
}
```

If any kind member has the required knowledge and the ability to help me then please type out a beginner-friendly response.

Here's a JSFiddle for the code: https://jsfiddle.net/7hb9bd58/2/

Comment: can you create a http://jsfiddle.net with the code and add the link to your fiddle to the question?

Comment: Thanks for the edit suggestion and comment, this is my first post here so I'm still working my way around the site. Added the jsfiddle at the bottom.

Comment: Try setting the position (`top: -10px;`)

Comment: Thank you so much for the help everybody - the final thing is, how do I mark this question as answered? Or is this not an option on this website? I can't find the answer in the tour or the help section. 

Thank you again all of you very kind members! I'm very impressed by the speed of response on top of the patience and kind attitudes shown today.

Comment: We are glad to help out! - the fiddle just speeds things up (helping us, help you :) ) - Welcome to StackOverflow!!! remember to read our [ask] page in the future for hints on how to ask great questions...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `.hhheader` height is not changing because, the margin on the `#logo` does not affect the header size (which depends on the size of the logo), you're only moving the `#logo`, nothing more.

Is there a reason why don't you just set the height of the `.hheader` element. Something like

```
height: 190px;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7hb9bd58/4/

**OR**, if you for some reason you are not allowed to do so, maybe you can just scale the logo, and it'll appear to overflow the header container

```
#logo {
    display:inline-block;
    transform: scale(1.3);
    margin-left:50px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7hb9bd58/5/

Comment: No, I considered it though following the tutorials I'm using to learn ATM I thought their was a reason concerning scaling as to why this was a bad idea. Though you absolutely seem to know your stuff so I thank you fully for both of your answers. Both great ideas and have taught me new features already.

Answer (score 1):

Set the position of your logo to absolute

```
#logo {
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    margin: -30px 0px -100px 10px;
}
```

This will remove the image from the flow, so it will no longer force .hheader's height to containe it.  To compensate, specify a height for hheader.  (I went with 190px, you can fine tune)

```
.hheader {
    height:190px;
/* rest of css */
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7hb9bd58/6/

Answer (score 0):

in css make changes ,change height according to your need

```
    .hheader {
      height:265px;
    }
 #logo {
    display: block;
    margin: 2px 0px -100px 10px;
    float: left;
}
```